# Adjust longtable length to caption length and vice versa

Tags: captions, longtable, lengths

Is there any way to adjust the `longtable` length to the `caption` length and vice versa?

Comment: Useful comment about the OP's document class: He uses the https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/harvard-phd, that as we can see in his questions breaks really many latex behaviors... I just have to mention it because the question is good, but an answer which using column types like p or m will not help the OP (but will help anyone else with a normal document class)

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and maybe draw a sketch of what the resulting table should look like?